# Dynamic SQL populate Triangulation / Cross-tab table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table, dynamic-sql, crosstab

Good day, 
i am having problems populating a matrix table that i have created that measures percentages of fall offs or cancelled over a selected date range.

Let me start at the beginning.
a date range parameter is selected eg. '2016-01-01' to '2016-12-31'. 
The code that i already have creates a matrix table which looks like:

```
MonthN  2016-01 2016-02 2016-03 ... 2016-12
2016-01
2016-02
2016-03
...
2016-12
```

i have a table that contains data with, for example, AccountNumber, Startdate and CancelDate.

what i need to do is populate the table created with values. 
eg. if in 2016-01 30 Accounts became active and 3 cancelled in the same month, the percentage is (@CxdPerentage = (@Cxd / @Active) * 100) = 10 (%) 
so in the first cell where the 2 dates correspond, the value will be 10
eg.

```
MonthN  2016-01 2016-02 2016-03 ... 2016-12
2016-01   10      null   null         null
2016-02  null     null   null         null  
2016-03  null     null   null         null  
...
2016-12  null     null   null         null
```

This would be created, i'm assuming the best way, with Dynamic Sql and a loop, which i have done and get a result like:

```
MonthN  2016-01 2016-02 2016-03 2016-04 ... 2016-12
2016-01   10      null   null    null        null
2016-02  null     5.00   null    null        null
2016-03  null     null   2.61    null        null
2016-04  null     null   null    1.96        null 
...
2016-12  null     null   null    null        3.12
```

the value for cross value 2016-02 and 2016-02 being 5.00 is derived by a calculation that works out all activated accounts on that month against all cancelled accounts in that month, so 40 were sold again and 2 cancelled in that month.

the next part is to populate the next entry DOWN and accross, so the table needs these values:

```
MonthN  2016-01 2016-02 2016-03 2016-04 ... 2016-12
2016-01   10      null   null    null        null
2016-02   13      6.60   null    null        null
2016-03  null     ????   2.61    null        null
2016-04  null     null   ????    1.96        null 
...
2016-12  null     null   null    ????        3.12
```

this would calculated from: IN 2016-01 30 Accounts became active, 3 of those were cancelled in the same month however, in the following month, 2016-02, 4 of the initial 30 cancelled, so the value there would be 4cxd / 30initial * 100 
((4 / 30) * 100) =  13 (% fall off)

the final result would look something similar to:
(Randoms numbers inserted to show outcome)

```
MonthN  2016-01 2016-02 2016-03 2016-04 ... 2016-12
2016-01  10.0     null   null    null        null
2016-02  13.0     6.60   null    null        null
2016-03  7.00     9.00   2.61    null        null
2016-04  5.00     8.00   5.00    1.96        null 
...
2016-12  8.00     9.65   5.20    6.50        3.12
```

in order to show you how i created the initial table(matrix) that i need populated, here is the code.

```
DROP TABLE Reporting.DBO.Stats_Dbs  -- Temp while im playing 
DECLARE @sDATE DATE = '2015-04-01', -- 24 months
        @eDATE DATE = '2017-04-01'
DECLARE @StatsStart DATE = @sDATE 
DECLARE @StatsEnd   DATE = @eDATE
DECLARE @Months TABLE (Months VARCHAR(10), StatsDB VARCHAR(12))
WHILE @StatsStart < @StatsEnd
BEGIN
    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Months 
            SELECT @StatsStart, 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),@StatsStart,120)
    END
    SET @StatsStart = DATEADD(MONTH, +1, (CONVERT(DATE, @StatsStart, 120)))
END

DECLARE @strQry VARCHAR(MAX) = 'CREATE TABLE Reporting.Dbo.Stats_Dbs(MonthN VARCHAR(10),'
SELECT @strQry += '['+ StatsDB +'] VARCHAR(100),' FROM @Months 
SELECT @strQry += ');'
PRINT(@strQry);
EXEC(@strQry);

INSERT INTO Reporting.DBO.Stats_Dbs(MonthN)
SELECT LEFT(Months, 7) FROM @Months
```

Can Anyone assist me ?

Comment: I believe i'm flogging a dead horse but really need this to work. :(

Comment: Just an FYI, with a little elbow grease and brain sweat, i solved the issue.